# The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Unexpected rethrowing"

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, ssl, mssql-jdbc

I'm using java 11, and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ), mssql-jdbc 9.4.1.jre11, as well as spring boot version is 2.4.4

when I try to connect through the jdbc to mssql server it throws some exception

here is the configuration for connect to server in my `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://serverip;database=MyDB;
spring.datasource.username=dbusername
spring.datasource.password=dbpassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

here is the console.log

```
2021-12-16 12:44:06.433  INFO 3999283 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-12-16 12:44:08.430 ERROR 3999283 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Unexpected rethrowing".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3422) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1916) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2970) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2628) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2471) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1470) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:915) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.lambda$h2Console$0(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:67) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.ifAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2035) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.h2Console(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:66) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:259) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:233) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.vino.app.VinoApplication.main(VinoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected rethrowing
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1383) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1291) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:435) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1824) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:decb5787-d1f3-4917-85c5-3a2fc7abf3f0
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:810) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:860) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:853) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1023) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:1013) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:457) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    ... 84 common frames omitted

2021-12-16 12:44:08.753  INFO 3999283 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-12-16 12:44:08.804  INFO 3999283 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-12-16 12:44:08.926  INFO 3999283 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-12-16 12:44:09.055  INFO 3999283 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-12-16 12:44:10.979 ERROR 3999283 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
```

please someone else suggests me to solve this problem.
I enable `TSLv1.2` from **Windows Server 2016** side and disabled `TSLv1`

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2010 - the next release after SQL Server 2008 R2 was SQL Server 2012. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70375306/edit) your question to include the output of `select @@version` when executed against your SQL Server - as text.

Comment: Aside... not related to your SSL/TLS issue, but `database=MyDB;` should be `databaseName=MyDB;`, see [Connection examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url#connection-examples).

Comment: Possibly related, your stack trace includes output from `mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar` ... seems like you have multiple versions of mssql-jdbc in your classpath.

Comment: If you still have problems after getting your classpath sorted out try reading through [The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Unexpected rethrowing". #879](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/879) for tips.

Comment: yes, I try with several versions, but same output, the stack trace I got when I run it jre8
now I have same issue with mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre11

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I able to connect db over the Intelij database tab
but problem is I unable to connect over program

Comment: now I get this

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]". ClientConnectionId:084c8d01-57d5-4b0a-93f6-c8b0d3a8852b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this property to application entry point

```
Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms","SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024,EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL");
```

if you use spring boot

you can use like this

```
import java.security.Security;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms","SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024,EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: does it have any security risk what does this means, and why do we need to use this?

Comment: Yes I think there have security issue too, problem is I cannot update mssql production server  TLS version and I try with several tools to connect over remote IP address of database, but cannot establish connection using jdbc driver, and using above code block I able to establish connection successfully, I think root case is java security packages updated but not able to connect using TLS 1.0 to access that have disable tls layer security, if someone know more that that looking good answer, Thanks

Comment: Could you confirm the specific algorithm we want to enable here instead of the complete property values?

Comment: @SumitJain I'm not sure that one. without adding that all I unable to access SQL server

Answer (score 2):

This issue got resolved for me when I replaced the sqljdbc-4.2.0 jar with **mssql-jdbc-8.4.1 jar**.

Another fixed for this error was enabling TLS 1.0 by iisencrypt.exe. However this solution to work needs your system to be restarted.
I would recommend to go with the first solution.

Add the below dependency in your pom.xml to add jar.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>8.4.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can add jar directly if it's not a maven project.